# Why is my MCU still getting powered even after I disconnect the main ground?

Tags: microcontroller, dc-dc-converter, ground

I have a board that consists of a DC to DC power supply that converts 24V DC line to 3.3V to power a microcontroller (ATMega AVR).

The mcu has a UART port to communicate with another board. At this point we will assume that we communicate with a desktop computer using a USB to UART cable (FTDI) which is also a real world scenario.

The level of the UART is 3.3V

The TX line of the UART is an open-drain output. There's a pull-up resistor at the other end to pull the line at high level.

The problem:
I noticed that when I disconnect the main ground from the board the MCU is still getting powered while the UART bus is connected.
Why is this happening?

This is happening even if the UART bus is at idle state.

I'm including a simplified block diagram of the circuit which by 90% is as simple as the real circuit.
[image]

The 100R resistors are only for protection.
The levels of the UART are correct and withing the specification.
The communication channel works fine.

I know it is getting powered because there are 10 LEDs on the board that blink with a certain pattern and some 7-segnent displays showing numbers according to the current state of the MCU.

Comment: Please draw your entire system, including what's on the other side of the UART connection and how that's grounded.

Comment: How are the grounds connected between everything in the system? It goes via some route you have not drawn, which is why simplifying is a bad idea.

Comment: It seems the AVR is powered via the uart pins. This is due to internal protection diodes present on most pins on a cmos ic.